# How to process Json array in android without square bracket

Tags: android, arrays, json

Raw Json Data

```
 [  
   {  
      "worker.1":{  
         "last_share":1443639029,
         "score":"3722204.62578",
         "alive":true,
         "shares":1124332,
         "hashrate":1047253
      },
      "worker.2":{  
         "last_share":1443639029,
         "score":"3794755.69049",
         "alive":true,
         "shares":1069332,
         "hashrate":1012070
      },
      "worker.3":{  
         "last_share":1440778690,
         "score":"0.0",
         "alive":false,
         "shares":0,
         "hashrate":0
      },
      "worker.4":{  
         "last_share":1443638222,
         "score":"940190.67723",
         "alive":true,
         "shares":449932,
         "hashrate":404772
      }
      "worker.nth":{  
         "last_share":1443638222,
         "score":"940190.67723",
         "alive":true,
         "shares":449932,
         "hashrate":404772
      }
   }
]
```

From the main question I have been able to narrow down the results and managed to add the Square bracket as well. Now i have a Json Array above so could someone advise me how can i process this Json array. Also note that it can end up being 1000 workers.

Please please help I have been breaking my head for 2 days on this,
Also note that the actual Json data is complex and 1000's of entries,
The json data included is just an overview.

Edit: Code that I ma using to process the above Json

```
try{
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonObj.getJSONObject("workers"));
                        if(jArray.length() == 0){
                            Log.d("Json Err", "JSON string has no entries");
                            return null;
                        }
                        JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

                        // To get one specific element:
                        JSONObject worker1 = jObject.getJSONObject("worker.1");
                        JSONObject worker2 = jObject.getJSONObject("worker.2");

                        // Iterate over all elements
                        Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();
                        while( keys.hasNext() ) {
                            String key = (String)keys.next(); // "worker.1", etc
                            if ( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
                                JSONObject entry = jObject.getJSONObject(key);
                                // Do something with your entry here like:
                                String score = entry.optString("score", "");
                                Boolean alive = entry.optBoolean("alive", false);
                                Integer shares = entry.optInt("shares", 0);
                                Log.d("Json Success", score );
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        Log.e("Json Err", "Failure converting JSON String", e);
                    }
```

Error that I am getting:

> E2570 (5:10 PM):
>       org.json.JSONException: Value {"worker.1":{"last_share":1443694390,"score":"15.6018529132","alive":true,"shares":59880,"hashrate":0},"worker.2":{"last_share":1443694180,"score":"2.97304689833","alive":true,"shares":2048,"hashrate":0},"worker.3":{"last_share":1440778690,"score":"0.0","alive":false,"shares":0,"hashrate":0},"ivonme.ant4":{"last_share":1443701343,"score":"8688.78118933","alive":true,"shares":203088,"hashrate":78633}}
>   of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
>               at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java)
>               at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java)
>               at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java)

Comment: this is a formal definition: "A **JSONArray** is an ordered sequence of values. Its external text form is a string wrapped in **square brackets** with commas separating the values.", so no: you cannot `"process Json array in android without square bracket"`

Comment: please post your raw JSON string. so it will be easy to figure out

Comment: I have updated the question with raw Data, can you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have...

```
   {  //JSONObject
      "worker.1":{  
         "last_share":1443639029,
         "score":"3722204.62578",
         "alive":true,
         "shares":1124332,
         "hashrate":1047253
      },
      "worker.2":{  
         "last_share":1443639029,
         "score":"3794755.69049",
         "alive":true,
         "shares":1069332,
         "hashrate":1012070
      } //,...
   }
```

To get all your workers you have to...

```
try{
   JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(yourStringFromYourQuestion);

   // To get one specific element:
   JSONObject worker1 = jObject.getJSONObject("worker.1");
   JSONObject worker2 = jObject.getJSONObject("worker.2");

   // Iterate over all elements
   Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();
   while( keys.hasNext() ) {
      String key = (String)keys.next(); // "worker.1", etc
      if ( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
         JSONObject entry = jObject.getJSONObject(key);
         // Do something with your entry here like:
         String score = entry.optString("score", "");
         Boolean alive = entry.optBoolean("alive", false);
         Integer shares = entry.optInteger("shares", 0);
      }
   }
} catch (JSONException e){
   Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failure converting JSON String", e);
}
```

Comment: i did, have a look now

Comment: But your square brackets are not necessary.. i think i didn't understand your initial question. If it's not too much work, you can keep them away. If you want to, just tell me and i'll edit my answer.

Comment: I have tried with the code that you provided however I am getting an error message saying JsonException. I have updated the question with the code you provided and with the output. Please can you help.. .

Comment: Seems like there are no square brackets (so there is no JSONArray wrapped around. Your JSON string is simply a JSONObject). Try my code i will edit right now, just a sec.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONArray jArray=jsonObj.getJSONArray("workers");
```

instead of

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonObj.getJSONObject("workers"));
```

The error is because of you are getting json array as object. I think so.